# What is an issue with Mother-in-Law's Tongue/ Snake Plant leaves getting dried up?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

Recently I bought a snake plant which I immediately re-potted to a slightly larger container. Shortly after brown liquid spots started appearing on the leaves as shown. What might be an issue and how to treat it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How long (in terms of days or weeks)  since you repotted it, and does the pot its in now have drainage holes in the bottom?

Comment: About a month ago, pot has a good drainage. Forgot to mention, liquid brown spots stopped appearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those corky looking areas are damage caused by something, could be infection, infestation or physical damage - if the liquid spots have stopped appearing, that's good, it may be the plant had a problem when you bought it that only showed itself once you got it home. I would cut or remove at the base all damaged leaves (in case it's infection), then see how it goes.